# if statement not taking input in strcmp string input

Tags: c, comparison, strcmp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

main() {
    char d[10];
    int value = 0, val1, val2;
    printf("Enter Day: ");
    scanf("%c", &d);

    val1 = strcmp(d, "sunday");
    val2 = strcmp(d, "saturday");
    
    if (val1 == 0) {
        printf("AS");
        value = 2;  
    } else
    if (val2 == 0) {
        value = 1;   
    } 
       
    switch (value) {
      case 2:
        printf("So sad, you will have to work");
        break;
      case 1:
        printf("Enjoy! its holiday");
        break;
      default:
        printf("Print valid character");
    }
}
```

I enter code here want to input days and to get some output using `switch` statement but `strcmp` is not working in `if` statement
I have to use a `switch` statement also
`if` statement not recognising value.

Comment: The notation `main() { … }` has been non-standard for the whole of this millennium; it was made non-standard in C99.  You should not be writing obsolete code!  You should explicitly specify the return type (`int`), and it is best to use `int main(void)` when your program does not heed command-line arguments.

Comment: The code shown does not use any feature from `<conio.h>` AFAICS; omit the header.  You should include a `break;` after the `default:` case, as a protection against future enhancements.  You should output a newline at the end of the various `printf()` statements — get into the habit of terminating outputs with newlines.

Comment: The bug: `scanf("%c",&d);`. Should be `%s`. Voting to close as simple typo.

Comment: You made the strcmp too complicated. You do not need an addtional switch. This makes the code more difficult to read.

Answer (score 2):

At least this problem:

`strcmp(d,"sunday")` expects array `d` to contain a *string*.

`d` does not certainly contain a *string* as no *null character* was assigned there.

```
char d[10];
printf("Enter Day: ");
scanf("%c",&d);  // Writes, at most, 1 character to `d`. Remainder of `d[]` is uninitialized.
```

Instead

```
if (scanf("%9s",d) == 1) {
  printf("Success, read <%s>\n", d);
```

---

Tip: Consider using `fgets()` to read user input.

Tip: Enable all compiler warnings to save time.